# Capistrano Capfile: what does >load 'deploy' do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

After running capify, the default Capfile always starts with:

```
load 'deploy'
```

I don't see a deploy.rb file on my load path when I >puts $" but I'm assuming this loads the default deploy recipes that come with capistrano?

Comment: The behaviour of `load` is documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Ruby Standard library documentation for `Kernel.load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load):

> #### load(filename, wrap=false) → true
>
> Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file filename. If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched for in the library directories listed in $:. If the optional wrap parameter is true, the loaded script will be executed under an anonymous module, protecting the calling program’s global namespace. In no circumstance will any local variables in the loaded file be propagated to the loading environment.

The `load 'deploy'` does exactly what you imagine that it does, it loads the `deploy.rb` from within Capistrano.

Comment: So in the Capfile if I do: puts $:    it doesn't list a file called deploy.rb which is why I'm confused. I found a deploy.rb in the capistrano gems directory thought in <gem dir>/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb but it's not on the the lib path.

Comment: Hmmmm, does load search recursively?  This is on the load path: vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib and the file in question is vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.13.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb?

Comment: I hate to seem stubborn, but the recipes directory is not in the GEM_PATH.  When you say 'Of course' are you saying that in reference to 'load' searching recursively from the .../capistrano-2.13.5/lib to find the deploy.rb under recipes?

Comment: Yes, and that "how does loading Gems work in Ruby" is a really, really widely asked, and answered question on SO. It has nothing specifically  relating to Capistrano, and all gems work this way. It also relates to how bundler works.

Comment: Ok so after investigating loading Gems, I'm finding that it is not recursive.  So if '.../capistrano-2.13.5/lib' is on the $LOAD_PATH, to load/require capistrano's deploy.rb, would mean you'd need >load 'capistrano/recipes/deploy'  but somehow it works by just doing >load 'deploy'

Comment: Capistrano modifies the `load` method. It' a common technique to load DSL files and have them work as expected.

Comment: Ahh, found it: @load_paths = [".", File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../recipes"))]  I under stand now.  Thanks!